# Vagrant Rsync Error before provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, rsync, provisioning, vagrant

So I'm having some adventures with the vagrant-aws plugin, and I'm now stuck on the issue of syncing folders. This is necessary to provision the machines, which is the ultimate goal. However, running `vagrant provision` on my machine yields

```
[root@vagrant-puppet-minimal vagrant]# vagrant provision
[default] Rsyncing folder: /home/vagrant/ => /vagrant
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed! 
mkdir -p '/vagrant'
```

I'm almost positive the error is caused because ssh-ing manually and running that command yields 'permission denied' (obviously, a non-root user is trying to make a directory in the root directory). I tried ssh-ing as root but it seems like bad practice. (and amazon doesn't like it) How can I change the folder to be rsynced with vagrant-aws? I can't seem to find the setting for that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe allow sudo and/or ask the plugin developer to use sudo when available. Personally I would allow a manually triggered server infrastructure provision taking place as root...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you are running into the known vagrant-aws issue [#72: Failing with EC2 Amazon Linux Images](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/72).

**Edit 3 (Feb 2014):** Vagrant 1.4.0 (released Dec 2013) and later versions now support the boolean configuration parameter `config.ssh.pty`.  Set the parameter to true to force Vagrant to use a PTY for provisioning.  Vagrant creator Mitchell Hashimoto [points out](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2731#issuecomment-31312336) that you must not set `config.ssh.pty` on the global config, you must set it on the node config directly.

This new setting should fix the problem, and you shouldn't need the workarounds listed below anymore. (But note that I haven't tested it myself yet.)  See [Vagrant's CHANGELOG](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for details -- unfortunately the `config.ssh.pty` option is not yet documented under [SSH Settings](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) in the Vagrant docs.

**Edit 2:** Bad news.  It looks as if even a `boothook` will not be "faster" to run (to update /etc/sudoers.d/ for `!requiretty`) than Vagrant is trying to rsync.  During my testing today I started seeing sporadic "mkdir -p /vagrant" errors again when running `vagrant up --no-provision`.  So we're back to the previous point where the most reliable fix seems to be a custom AMI image that already includes the applied patch to `/etc/sudoers.d`.

**Edit:** Looks like I found a more reliable way to fix the problem.  Use a [boothook](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/format.html#cloud-boothook) to perform the fix.  I manually confirmed that a script passed as a `boothook` is executed before Vagrant's rsync phase starts.  So far it has been working reliably for me, and I don't need to create a custom AMI image.

Extra tip: And if you are relying on `cloud-config`, too, you can create a [Mime Multi Part Archive](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/format.html#mime-multi-part-archive) to combine the `boothook` and the `cloud-config`.  You can get the latest version of the [write-mime-multipart](https://raw.github.com/lovelysystems/cloud-init/master/tools/write-mime-multipart) helper script from GitHub.

Usage sketch:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://raw.github.com/lovelysystems/cloud-init/master/tools/write-mime-multipart
$ chmod +x write-mime-multipart
$ cat boothook.sh
#!/bin/bash
SUDOERS_FILE=/etc/sudoers.d/999-vagrant-cloud-init-requiretty
echo "Defaults:ec2-user !requiretty" > $SUDOERS_FILE
echo "Defaults:root !requiretty" >> $SUDOERS_FILE
chmod 440 $SUDOERS_FILE

$ cat cloud-config
#cloud-config

packages:
  - puppet
  - git
  - python-boto

$ ./write-mime-multipart boothook.sh cloud-config > combined.txt
```

You can then pass the contents of 'combined.txt' to aws.user_data, for instance via:

```
aws.user_data = File.read("/tmp/combined.txt")
```

Sorry for not mentioning this earlier, but I am literally troubleshooting this right now myself. :)

### Original answer (see above for a better approach)

**TL;DR**: The most reliable fix is to "patch" a stock Amazon Linux AMI image, save it and then use the customized AMI image in your `Vagrantfile`.  See below for details.

#### Background

A potential workaround is described (and linked in the bug report above) at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/pull/70/files.  In a nutshell, add the following to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
aws.user_data = "#!/bin/bash\necho 'Defaults:ec2-user !requiretty' > /etc/sudoers.d/999-vagrant-cloud-init-requiretty && chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/999-vagrant-cloud-init-requiretty\nyum install -y puppet\n"
```

Most importantly this will configure the OS to not require a tty for user `ec2-user`, which seems to be the root of the problem.  I /think/ that the additional installation of the `puppet` package is not required for the actual fix (although Vagrant may use Puppet for provisioning the machine later, depending on how you configured Vagrant).

#### My experience with the described workaround

I have tried this workaround but Vagrant still occasionally fails with the same error.  It might be a "race condition" where Vagrant happens to run its rsync phase faster than cloud-init (which is what `aws.user_data` is passing information to) can prepare the workaround for #72 on the machine for Vagrant.  If Vagrant is faster you will see the same error; if cloud-init is faster it works.

#### What will work (but requires more effort on your side)

What definitely works is to run the command on a stock Amazon Linux AMI image, and then save the modified image (= create an image snapshot) as a custom AMI image of yours.

```
# Start an EC2 instance with a stock Amazon Linux AMI image and ssh-connect to it
$ sudo su - root
$ echo 'Defaults:ec2-user !requiretty' > /etc/sudoers.d/999-vagrant-cloud-init-requiretty
$ chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/999-vagrant-cloud-init-requiretty

# Note: Installing puppet is mentioned in the #72 bug report but I /think/ you do not need it
#       to fix the described Vagrant problem.
$ yum install -y puppet
```

You must then use this custom AMI image in your `Vagrantfile` instead of the stock Amazon one.  The obvious drawback is that you are not using a stock Amazon AMI image anymore -- whether this is a concern for you or not depends on your requirements.

#### What I tried but didn't work out

For the record: I also tried to pass a `cloud-config` to `aws.user_data` that included a [bootcmd](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html) to set `!requiretty` in the same way as the embedded shell script above.  According to the cloud-init docs `bootcmd` is run "very early" in the startup cycle for an EC2 instance -- the idea being that `bootcmd` instructions would be run earlier than Vagrant would try to run its rsync phase.  But unfortunately I discovered that the `bootcmd` feature is not implemented in the outdated `cloud-init` version of current Amazon's Linux AMIs (e.g. ami-05355a6c has cloud-init 0.5.15-69.amzn1 but [bootcmd was only introduced in 0.6.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+changelog)).

Comment: Thanks so much! I put in the line you suggested as a temporary fix, it seems to work, and I will be creating a custom AMI for my needs anyway, so I will keep this in mind when I do. Answered my question AND the follow-up question "isn't that fix kind of sketchy.." I would have had.

Comment: You are welcome! See my edit to my original answer -- I think I just found a better way  to fix the problem.  It uses ``aws.user_data`` but with a ``boothook``.  So far it seems to work very reliably for me.

Comment: Addendum:  Bad news.  It looks as if even a ``boothook`` will not be "faster" to run (to update /etc/sudoers.d/ for ``!requiretty``) than Vagrant is trying to rsync.  During my testing today I started seeing sporadic "mkdir -p /vagrant" errors again when running ``vagrant up --no-provision``.

Comment: Same error has just started happening for me. No longer able to rsync with aws.user_data or manually editing the file.

Comment: I updated my answer again because Vagrant 1.4.0+ supports the ``config.ssh.pty`` option now, which should fix the problem (set the option to true).